# PHP SOAP returning SOAP Fault: Server was unable to process request with .asmx Web Service

Tags: php, soap, asmx

I am having difficulty in getting a SOAP request working properly , which requires XML string as input.

It's throwing

**"SOAP Fault: Server was unable to process request. ---> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s"**

no matter what input i send , i have used nusoap but to no avail , PHP  soap library.
The code i am using is:

```
<?
$aOptions = array(
'location' => 'http://webserviceurl.asmx',
'uri' => 'http://tempuri.org/',
"style" => SOAP_RPC,
"use" => SOAP_ENCODED
);
$client = new SOAPClient(null, $aOptions);

$request ='<item xmlns="rmsItem">
      <columns>
        <column>description</column>
        <column>department</column>
        <column>brand</column>
        <column>lastsold</column>
        <column>lastupdated</column>
        <column>quantityonhand</column>
        <column>weight</column>
      </columns>
      <filters>
        <filter>
          <filterColumn>quantityonhand</filterColumn>
          <operator>greaterthan</operator>
          <filterValue>20</filterValue>
        </filter>
        <filter>
          <filterColumn>lastsold</filterColumn>
          <operator>greaterthan</operator>
          <filterValue>01-01-2005</filterValue>
        </filter>
      </filters>
      <sortColumns>
        <sortColumn>
          <sortColumnName>lastsold</sortColumnName>
          <sortType>ascending</sortType>
        </sortColumn>
        <sortColumn>
          <sortColumnName>quantityonhand</sortColumnName>
          <sortType>descending</sortType>
        </sortColumn>
      </sortColumns>
    </item>';

//$result = $client->__soapCall('getAllInfo',array('infoRequestXml'=>(string)($request),'errorMessage'=>'') ,array('soapaction' => 'http://webserviceurl/getAllInfo'));

$soapvar = new SoapVar($request , XSD_ANYXML);

$params = array("infoRequestXml" => $soapvar);

//print_r($params);
//$result = $this->soapclient->__soapCall("SaveItem", array("parameters"=>$params), null, $this->soapheaders);
try
{
$result=$client->__soapCall('getAllInfo',array("parameters"=>$params),array('soapaction' => 'http://webserviceurl/getAllInfo'));
}
catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo "SOAP Fault: ".$e->getMessage()."<br />\n";
}
echo "<pre>\n";
echo htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest())."\n";
echo "Response:\n".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse())."\n";
echo "</pre>"; 

var_dump($result);

?>
```

I am banging my head against a wall from last two days, searched google for this problem but got no answer that solves or guide me through.

Anyone who can throw some light on this will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run the XML through SOAPVar, and take advantage of the WSDL option of your web service if you can:

```
<?php

$client = new SOAPClient(
    'http://webserviceurl.asmx?WSDL',
    array(
        'location' => 'http://webserviceurl.asmx',
        'trace' => 1,
        'style' => SOAP_RPC,
        'use' => SOAP_ENCODED,
    )
);

$request = '<item xmlns="rmsItem">
      <columns>
        <column>description</column>
        <column>department</column>
        <column>brand</column>
        <column>lastsold</column>
        <column>lastupdated</column>
        <column>quantityonhand</column>
        <column>weight</column>
      </columns>
      <filters>
        <filter>
          <filterColumn>quantityonhand</filterColumn>
          <operator>greaterthan</operator>
          <filterValue>20</filterValue>
        </filter>
        <filter>
          <filterColumn>lastsold</filterColumn>
          <operator>greaterthan</operator>
          <filterValue>01-01-2005</filterValue>
        </filter>
      </filters>
      <sortColumns>
        <sortColumn>
          <sortColumnName>lastsold</sortColumnName>
          <sortType>ascending</sortType>
        </sortColumn>
        <sortColumn>
          <sortColumnName>quantityonhand</sortColumnName>
          <sortType>descending</sortType>
        </sortColumn>
      </sortColumns>
    </item>';

$result = array();

$params = array("infoRequestXml" => $request);

try {
    $result = $client->__soapCall('getAllInfo', array("parameters"=>$params));
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo "SOAP Fault: ".$e->getMessage()."<br />\n";
}

echo "<pre>";
echo htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequestHeaders())."\n";
echo htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest())."\n";
echo "Response:\n".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponseHeaders())."\n";
echo htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse())."\n";
echo "</pre>"; 

var_dump($result);

?>
```

Comment: ....Thanks a Lot Pete .. It worked like a charm... You saved my day....If u don't mind can i ask you one more thing , could you just point me what actually i was doing wrong so next time i dont mess thing up again..As i'm new to this PHP SOAP scenario... how will I access my resultant XML from the result array... Thanks a lot again for your valuable time and thoughts....

Comment: I got the response working and after converting the Object returned into an array and passing that desired element of array to **simplexml_load_string()**...